# Android save state before ondestroy()

Tags: android, state, ondestroy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Saving a state during Android lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829844/android-saving-a-state-during-android-lifecycle)

i want to save some values in a file before the user terminates the activity.In which method should i implement this?

Apart from using a file , or sql lite is there a way of storing complex data such as a layout (that has dynamically  changed ) ?

"onDestroy() Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layouts are bound to the context of the Activity that holds it, so you do no want to save full `View` objects to files because the Activity that it's attached to is void.

The easiest method (depending on the amount and type of data you want to save) is using the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) library.  It's a file I/O wrapper that makes saving and retrieving data pretty simple.  You can save the specific layout data in the `onPause()` method, the rebuild the layout with the specifications in `onResume()`.

If the data you need is too complex for `SharedPreferences`, you'll have to save it to use other methods for saving (found in that link).  The process for rebuilding the layouts will be the same.

Comment: if i have for example a tablelayout that has been changed and new rows have been added(2 textview each row , 10 rows ),i should  retrieve each row's contents , save them , and rebuild the layout in onResume?
the file that i mentioned above was used to save 2 integers (for practice)

Comment: Yes.  Save them using one of the methods in `onPause()` (when the Activity leaves view) and rebuild them in `onResume()` (when the Activity is about to come into view).

Answer (score 1):

I would call all the stuff you want to pass to the bundle in your onPause method. Here is some stuff on the [android lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and why not try storing stuff in csv if you want to load from file. (comma seperated values) (althoughthat is mainly used for tile based games)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SharedPreferences` , refer the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) , and this [tutorial](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html) to understand how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the data using a SharedPreference? Here are the android docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref